# In Android Studio. Android Virtual device is not booting. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio

Once I run my app, this is all I could see in the console.

Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd prabhu -netspeed full -netdelay none

Nothing is coming up after this message. Why my AVD is not running ??

Comment: How long did you wait?  It is not a fast process.

Comment: waited for more than 30 mins ... it never turned up

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea based on the information provided, but may I suggest http://www.genymotion.com/ which is much more responsive than the built in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to Launch my emulator after editing my AVD!

This may help someone. The issues was my target API was 20 (Android L) and I marked load emulator from snapshot.

Once I undo check in Launch emulator from snapshot , the issue got resolved.